# NameError in Python despite function already being defined?

Tags: python

I'm trying out a LeetCode challenge in Python but haven't been able to run the code yet as I keep getting this NameError. I've tried to research the problem but the only solution I have found is that 'longestSubstring' should be defined before 'lengthofLongestSubstring', which it already is. I'm not too sure what the problem is, can anyone help? Sorry if the answer is glaringly obvious.
(also sorry if the actual solution to the challenge is poor, this is my first attempt and I haven't been able to test the logic of it yet)

```
class Solution:

def longestSubstring(s: str) -> int:
    #variable to keep count of the length of the current substring, and another to store the length of the longest substring yet
    count = 0
    longest = 0
    
    #temp array to store the characters already encountered in that substring
    temp = []        
    
    for element in s:
        if element in temp:
            if count > longest:
                longest = count
            count = 0
            temp.clear()
            break
        else:
            s.append(element)
            count=count+1
    
    return longest
    
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    #variable currentBest to keep count of the length of the current substring, and another to store the length of the longest substring yet. Initially set to longest substring from first run.       
    currentBest = longestSubstring(s)
    
    tot = s.length
    
    for x in range(tot):
        output = longestSubstring(s[1:])
        if output > currentBest:
            currentBest = output
    
    return currentBest
```

Edit: Here's the error message:

> NameError: name 'longestSubstring' is not defined

> currentBest = longestSubstring(s)

> Line 38 in lengthOfLongestSubstring (Solution.py)

Comment: "as I keep getting this NameError" Which NameError? The text seems to say only *that* you get *some* NameError, not any details on it. Please [edit] your question to include the traceback. Consider to review the [ask] and [mre] help pages as well.

Comment: `longestSubString` eiher needs to accept `self` or be decorated as a `@staticmethod`. Also since these are class methods they must call each other as e.g.`self.longestSubstring()`

Comment: Make `longestSubstring` accept `self` like match said and then call `self.longestSubstring` in the second method. Also, you should include your error as MisterMiyagi said otherwise it's very hard to know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Note that these aren't functions, they are methods. That means you have to call ``self.longestSubstring(s)`` instead of ``longestSubstring(s)``, for example.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi @match @hyper-neutrino Sorry for the late reply and thanks for all your feedback! Changing to `self.longestSubstring(s)` did the trick, the error message that I wrote at the bottom of my post was all the given regarding the NameError. Now working through some other errors..